Can I run a one-phase AC capacitor motor from a three-phase VFD?
I'm building an art installation and found a cheap but strong AC Motor with capacitor. So by my understanding it is a one-phase capacitor run motor. The shield with the specs is very old and hardly readable but it definitely says 1600W and maybe it says 8A. The motor comes out of a lawnmower. I attached a wielded arm which is going to spin around to occasionally kick a football. Because the rpm, once reached are far to high I used a time switch to turn it on 3 sec and then off for 4sec and repeat. For me that works but the motor started to get very hot..! I learned that for the startup it may consume up to 7 times the power it runs on which is why the high on-off frequency is a huge problem for an ac motor. So now I'm trying to get a VFD which i can speed control to a rpm that is low enough so it can just stay on. But apparently these VFD's are very expansive and also not so easy to find. I found a couple second hand VFD's that come close to what I need. Although they have single phase 230V input they all have three-phase output.
Now, can i still run my motor with it? Can I just wire the two cables that go from the capacitor to the motor to the second phase of the VFD and leave the third phase unused? I read something in a forum from 20 years ago that someone did that but it is not described how they did it.
My plan B would be to get a easier to find start-up current limiter to reduce the heat when i still turn on and off repeatedly. Although I feel that could lower the starting torque, which could cause a problem.
Then complete other field would be to get a direct current Motor, but this would be a huge gamble because i have no iead how that would work with the weight of the arm and the kicking and I only have two weeks left.
I ll attach fotos of the motor I am currently using and the arm which is attached.
Thanks for helping!
Sebastian
-UPDATE-
I found a VFD that works. It's a Invertek Optidrive E3 - IP20. It came pre configured. Just picked it up today. I will post more details, when I know more.




Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

RSS, what's stopping you from using a reduction gearbox?

@periblepsis i want to be able to change the speed on the go. also i feel like fiddling around with gears is a whole other project. that's some engineering type beat
